# multiple buttons in one ActionRow

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm using the discord.js library and node.js to create a Discord bot that can send a DM to a user containing buttons.

I want to send a Discord message with multiple buttons, each with a unique customId and label. My current method is using an list of buttons. I use a for loop adding button objects to the list, and pass it in to the components of the .send method as a list.

```
x = 5
buttons = []

for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    buttons.push(new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
        new MessageButton()
            .setCustomId(i.toString())
            .setLabel(messageSplit[i])
            .setStyle('PRIMARY')
        )
    )
}

msg.reply({ embeds: [embedRecipient], components: buttons })
```

This works, but each button is an new ActionRow of its own and thus resulting in the buttons being on different lines. What I mean: [image of buttons each on a different line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7Hd8.png)

How can I make it so the same features (like customId and Label) of the buttons retain but they are all on the same line? Making them all in the same one ActionRow should solve this I don't know the code to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

To put all the buttons in one single `MessageActionRow`, you could just declare the row outside the for loop and then inside it, you can just use `.addComponents()` to add a button to the `MessageActionRow`. An example is this:

```js
x = 5
const buttons = new MessageActionRow()

for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    buttons.addComponents(
        new MessageButton()
            .setCustomId(i.toString())
            .setLabel(messageSplit[i])
            .setStyle('PRIMARY')
        )
    )
}

msg.reply({ embeds: [embedRecipient], components: [buttons] })
```

Comment: But the buttons variable is a `MessageActionRow`. All I am doing is creating the `MessageActionRow` and then adding all the buttons in a for loop

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a bot and I read this and the answers but I used this solution based on reading discord docs:
An Action Row is a non-interactive container component for other types of components.

You can have up to 5 Action Rows per message
An Action Row cannot contain another Action Row
you can assign an action row object to `const row` and then you can add components to the row without using loop so it gives you clearer code

```
 const Discord = require('discord.js');
 //assign action row object to row const 

const row = new Discord.MessageActionRow();

//add components to row up to 5 times 
        row.addComponents(new Discord.MessageButton()
            .setStyle("SECONDARY")
            .setEmoji("")
            .setLabel("create ticket")
            .setCustomId("create-ticket")

        );
        row.addComponents(new Discord.MessageButton()
        .setStyle("SECONDARY")
        .setEmoji("")
        .setLabel("admin options")
        .setCustomId("create-tic")

    );
```

[3 buttons in action row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkqyG.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).